# How to setup NS Record to External Name Server from Internal DNS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

We have the following scenario:

1. Our company has an **Internal DNS** & an **External DNS** server.
2. Both of them holds the same domain (example.com).
3. Our **Internal DNS** is a Windows Server that cannot access the Internet, but has setup forwarders for "All others DNS" to the **External DNS**
4. We need to setup a sub-domain (vendor.exmaple.com) to an Authoritative name server (ns1.vendor.com) from vendor and the vendor will provide the IP-address for this sub-domain.
5. And, we have setup the following in our **External DNS** for Internet people who needs to access the name (vendor.example.com).

   ```
   vendor IN NS ns1.outsider.com
   ```

So that when Internet people queries the sub-domain

```
nslookup vendor.example.com
```

It returns with the corresponding IP-address defined in our vendor name server (ns1.vendor.com)

---

Now, we encountered the problem that:

If we apply the same setting into our **Internal DNS** server, we got "Server fails" when an internal staff uses 'nslookup' to query "vendor.example.com" when going through the **Internal DNS**.

If I use 'dig' with '+nssearch' to query from my PC to our **Internal DNS**,

```
C:\>dig +nssearch vendor.example.com
;; reply from unexpected source: <Our Proxy Server>#<Number>, expected <IP of ns1.vendor.com>#53
;; reply from unexpected source: <Our Proxy Server>#<Number>, expected <IP of ns1.vendor.com>#53
;; reply from unexpected source: <Our Proxy Server>#<Number>, expected <IP of ns1.vendor.com>#53

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5 <<>> +nssearch vendor.example.com
;; global options: +short +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

We expected that when the request goes to our **Internal DNS**, it will forward the request to our **External DNS** and get the IP-address from the vendor name server.  Then, respond to the PC inside our company network.

---

Could anyone tell me what's wrong on this?  And, how we can this correctly?

Comment: The results with `dig` rather sounds like your have something in your network that intercepts 53/udp traffic and which provides responses but with the wrong source address compared to where the query was sent?

Comment: Either that or asymmetric routing.

Comment: @AndrewB Regular routing (asymmetric or otherwise) does not change the source address, though?

Comment: @Håkan If a SNAT is involved on the return path, it's possible. I didn't say anything about *good* routing...

Comment: We found that the 

> ;; reply from unexpected source ...

is due to the Internal DNS server cannot access Internet to query ns1.vendor.com

Therefore, everytime when it queries "ns1.vendor.com", it was being redirected to our Proxy server and blocked there.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding you can try several things:

1. Create a CNAME Entry vendor.example.com on internalDNS holding the information externaldns.example.com. On externaldns.example.com you configured the NS Entry(s) holding the Server responsible for that zone.
   When a computer queries internalDNS it delegates the resolution of the DN to externalDNS. This server delegates it over to server.vendor.com which holds the actual information.
2. Configure all Computers (with help of a GPO) that have access to the internet in that way, that their DNS queries will directly go to externaldns.example.com. So you don't need any entry on internalDNS.

The Second possibility is only applicable if the internal Computers are not able to access the internet. If this is not the case, you should rethink your Network architecture and the reason why you have two seperate nameservers (this is not clear out of your description).

Answer (score -1):

setup a conditional forwarder for this sub-domain, pointing to ns1.vendor.com (assuming ns1.vendor.com is resolvable internally)

Comment: Since our Internal DNS server cannot access to the Internet directly, it cannot point to ns1.vendor.com.  Can we point this to our External DNS server?  In addition, if we are doing this, should we remove the NS record from the Internal DNS server first?